# The New Year or New Year

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

Do we use articles with the names of celebrations? Maybe we can but haven't got to, that is, it's optional?

- I shan't have written my essay by the time [the] New Year begins.

Comment: Unless you're talking about Chinese (or Persian) New Year, the name of the celebration isn't *New Year* but *New Year's Eve*, and it happens on the last day of the old year.

Comment: Are you talking about the beginning of New Year celebrations, or just the new year of 2023?

Comment: I mean in general, do we use articles with the names of celebrations?

Answer (score 1):

Notice how these two differ:

1. I shan't have written my essay before New Year’s Day.
2. I shan't have written my essay before the new year begins.

We don't usually think of there being a particular holiday named *New Year* in English. We can speak of *New Year’s Day* and *New Year’s Eve*, but that’s all. We would use no capitals here, either:

3. The first day of the new year came and went with my essay unwritten, and indeed unbegun.

But you shouldn't count on capital letters. For one thing, older writing might use *New Year* here just as it might use *Summer* or
*Winter* even though we seldom write them that way any longer.

More importantly, you can't hear capital letters in speech. You have to listen for grammatical changes to signal what's what.

That is not to say that you can ***never*** ever use an article or other determiner with  a proper name. But by default, proper names are ***already marked for definiteness***. That’s why you cannot use them here:

4. We didn't see them until Christmas.
5. We wouldn't be ready before December.

You don't need a determiner there because we know which one you're talking about. It's just like with John or Mary.

The places you can and do use an indefinite article are those where you are calling out a particular one of many of the same thing.

6. That year we had a Christmas like no other.
7. The further they receded in time and memory, the more fondly would I come to look upon the Christmases of my youth.
8. We didn't have a very memorable New Year's Eve celebration the year our Christmas tree burned down our house.
9. Mary, there's a (or *some*) John Smith on the phone asking about your mother.

## Personal names are definite by default

You're mistaking common names with personal (sometimes called "proper") names. "Proper" names of things have special grammar attached to them in English because they're the name of just one thing. Names that designate one particular thing do not take determiners in English, no matter whether that’s Fido or February, Craig or Christmas, Susan or September.

Only when there are many such things under discussion need we some way to determine which of all those Christmases or Susans you mean.

Comment: Some perhaps less well known &/or non-Christian festival days, like 'The Assumption', 'The Day of Atonement', also take the definite article, but it's arguably welded into the proper noun. 'The First Day of Christmas' etc also need articles. A nice overview, and 'calling out' needs a chapter in the next improved grammar (or is the canon now fixed?)